# How can I generate an order which due date is uniformly chosen from 4 fixed due dates?

Tags: java, anylogic, job-scheduling

I am modelling a job shop process with single, identical parallel machines. For the order arrival process, I want to generate orders. The due date of an order has to be either 18:00:00 PM, 19:00:00 PM, 20:00:00 PM or 21:00:00 PM. When an order is generated, its due date should be set, and should be randomly chosen from the 4 mentioned times. Each time/due date has the same probability of getting chosen. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I used the following at *Action* of an *Event* for setting the due date of an order to 18:00:00 PM

```
`Order order = new Order();
// Set due date as fixed time
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
order.atrDueDate1 = cal1.getTime();
order.atrID= 10;
order.markParametersAreSet();
enter.take(order);`
```

However, I do not want to fix the due date for all generated orders to 18:00:00 PM, but in the way I described before (chosen from the 4 times)

Comment: What is inside calendar? Only these 4 datetimes?

Comment: currently, by using this part with calendar, the output of cal1.getTime() is the time 18:00:00 PM (as I specified this time with cal1.set)

Comment: Create an array with all the possible due date options and then randomly select one with the function `randomFrom()`. Read more here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/selecting-random.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Do you know how I could create an array that has the times [18:00:00 19:00:00 20:00:00 21:00:00] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,uniform_discr(18,21));
```

Nevertheless be careful, you should always do this when you create an agent using new Agent().. this will avoid lots of problems

```
order.createAndStart(main);
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, however all the time slots between these values are a possibilitie as well. However, I would like to just have the possibility for specific times. Lets say, 18:00:00, 18:30:00 and 19:20:00. But not the possibility that the time is set to 18:23:57. Do you know how I can avoid this?

Comment: please ask a new stackoverflow question for this